# How can i select multiple items grouped by index from list?

Tags: vb.net, linq, select

i have a list

```
Dim list1 As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)() From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

i want select three items from list1 in order of index to list2.

```
List2   = {"123" ,  "456",  "789"}
```

How can i select them without for next loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a LINQ query for you without visible loops as desired:

```
Dim itemGroups As List(Of String) = list1.
    Select(Function(b, i) New With {.Byte = b, .Index = i}).
    GroupBy(Function(x) x.Index \ 3).
    Select(Function(g) String.Concat(g.Select(Function(x) x.Byte))).
    ToList()
```

`x.Index \ 3` is used to build the groups of three, it's the [integer division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx) that discards any remainder and retains only the integer portion. (For C# users: it is the same as `/` for you)